# Itk geodesicActiveContour Error

Tags: itk

I'm actualy working on a geodesiActiveContour segmentation with itk in Medical 3D image dimension.
When i use the FastMarchinFiltre with initialDistance=6 the geodesicActiveContour get me this error :
itk::ERROR: Region ImageRegion 
size [256,256,181]
is OutSide of Buffered Region ImageRegion 
size[0,0,0]
Here is My code :

```
InputImageType::IndexType  seedPosition;
  NodeContainer::Pointer seeds = NodeContainer::New();
  NodeType node;
  seedPosition[0] = seedPosX;//+i;
  seedPosition[1] = seedPosY;//+i;
  seedPosition[2] = seedPosZ;//+i;

  seeds->Initialize();
  seedPosition[0] = seedPosition[0];
  seedPosition[1] = seedPosition[1];
  seedPosition[2] = seedPosition[2];

  node.SetValue( seedValue );
  node.SetIndex( seedPosition );

  seeds->InsertElement( 0, node );

  fastMarching->SetTrialPoints( seeds );
  fastMarching->SetSpeedConstant( 1.0);
  fastMarching->SetOutputSize(caster->GetOutput()->GetBufferedRegion().GetSize() );
  fastMarching->SetOutputSpacing(caster->GetOutput()->GetSpacing());
  fastMarching->SetStoppingValue(10);

//Geodesic

CastFilterType::Pointer caster2 = CastFilterType::New();
  caster2->SetInput(fastMarching->GetOutput());
  caster2->SetOutputMaximum(0);
  caster2->SetOutputMaximum(255);

  typedef  itk::GeodesicActiveContourLevelSetImageFilter< InputImageType, InputImageType >  GeodesicActiveContourFilterType;
  GeodesicActiveContourFilterType::Pointer geodesicActiveContour = GeodesicActiveContourFilterType::New();
  geodesicActiveContour->SetPropagationScaling( 4.0 );
  geodesicActiveContour->SetCurvatureScaling( 1.0 );
  geodesicActiveContour->SetAdvectionScaling( 1.0 );
  geodesicActiveContour->SetMaximumRMSError( 0.02 );
  geodesicActiveContour->SetNumberOfIterations( numberOfIterations );
  geodesicActiveContour->SetInput( caster2->GetOutput() );
  geodesicActiveContour->SetFeatureImage( caster->GetOutput() );
```

Can anyone Help me on This??

Comment: Where do you set the initial distance in your code? Are you sure that you are assigning it to the seedvalue and not to the seed position? see also the example http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/Examples_2Segmentation_2ThresholdSegmentationLevelSetImageFilter_8cxx-example.html  ( it should be also in the itk guide)

Comment: In your code you also don't put where caster comes from. What is the value of caster->GetOutput()->GetBufferedRegion().GetSize() ? If it's [0,0,0] , probably something went wrong reading the initial image

Comment: Thank you a lot Dude, But the problem is i can show the image of the caster normaly But caster->GetOutput()->GetBufferedRegion().GetSize()  returns me [0,0,0]... How can i fix that?

Comment: Sorry to insist, are you sure that you can see correctly the image after the caster? The problem seems to be there, not in the code you posted. You also say that you have an error with initial distance=6, but at this point I would expect that it doesn't work also with other distances...unless you have something like a loop that somehow changes the distance and modifies the caster?

Comment: Yes i'm sure..the caster is a caste a of intensity between 0 and 255 of a segmoid Filter ,alpha= -50 an Beta=5 and i can see the image after the filter Normaly, and yes i tried with many distances and the error dosn't change so the problem seems came from the Size of BuffuredRegion

Comment: Then you should update the question (also the code)

Comment: You can also try to use GetLargestPossibleRegion http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/insight-users/2005-November/015645.html

Comment: Thank you, i tried GetLargestPossibleRegion but the size stays [0,0,0].

Comment: i'll update my question as you advise... thanks a lot